# Load dll at runtime but reference at programming time?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I would like to ask a question regarding static & dynamic dll referencing in C#. In my application, I need to reference to a dll, I included it in my project references, so far, this was good. But soon I really that I need to load/unload required dll at runtime, so I do search & read some articles about dynamic dll load/unload using AppDomain. The problem of referencing this way is that I have to use Reflection to obtain the classes & methods info, then create objects, invoke methods, bla bla... This is quite complicated & I have to change my entire code, which has already been tested & delivered. Is there any way to have the dll reference at the development (project references) but can be load/unload dynamically at runtime?

I think I have seen one example for this, it is the Microsoft Interop services, I wrote a program to work with Excel, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, when browse a method, it will have a prefix "dynamic" before the method name.

Have any one encounter this problem before? And any solution suggested? Thanks for answers.

Comment: can you show us a simple example with codes?

Comment: @Raptor for example, I have a tool API (provided as dll reference) which support automation:
`SomeTool tool = SomeTool.GetInstance();
Console.WriteLine(tool.GetVersion());
tool.PerformTask1();
tool.PerformTask2();
// after all
tool.Close();`
now I want to load/unload this dll at runtime, but still keep my functional code.

Comment: Hit the magical **edit** button to update your question please.

Comment: My first idea is to use interfaces to mark the methods in your DLLs and use said interfaces in code, then load and unload DLLs implementing these interfaces as needed. That is, assuming you can use interfaces.

Comment: You already know what you need to do.  If that starts to look like a major pita, like it is, then maybe you'll like to tone down the "dynamic referencing" requirement.  Or byte the bullet, there's no lack of examples on how to make plug-ins work in .NET.  You don't need us to add yet another one.